# Symfony2 Gedmo Tree with Translatable listner

Tags: php, symfony, tree, translation

I'm using Gedmo Tree in my Symfony2 project.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$options = array(
    'decorate' => true,
    'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
    'rootClose' => '</ul>',
    'childOpen' => '<li>',
    'childClose' => '</li>',
    'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
        return '<a class="menu" href="#">'.$node['name'].'</a>';
    }
);


$category = $em->getRepository('MyMainBundle:Category')->childrenHierarchy(
    null, /* starting from root nodes */
    false, /* load all children, not only direct */
    $options
);

print_R($category);
```

It works, but problem is that field name is translatable. In category table it's NULL and values saved in category_translations table, but my code returns only fields from category table.

Tried add listners:

```
$evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager();

$translatableListener = new \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener();
$translatableListener->setTranslatableLocale('en');
$evm->addEventSubscriber($translatableListener);
```

And change:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

with:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(null,null,$evm);
```

but didn't helped.

Read about [query hint](https://gist.github.com/1086164), but don't have query to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work :
Create a **Custom NestedTreeRepository** and override **getNodesHierarchyQuery** method to call **setHint** on the returned **query**.

```
namespace My\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository;

/**
 * CategoryRepository
 */
class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getNodesHierarchyQuery($node = null, $direct = false, array $options = array(), $includeNode = false)
    {
        $query = $this->getNodesHierarchyQueryBuilder($node, $direct, $options, $includeNode)->getQuery();
        $query->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
        );
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to assign your repository to your entity :

```
namespace My\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about overriding query function.